# How can convert a .HAR/ JSON file into readable .txt file? (Extract youtube live chat)

Tags: php, parsing, youtube-api

**I need your help, please, with the following:**

I would like to use these instructions to export the chat history from a YouTube livestream and make it readable.

1. Instructions: [PHP Extract youtube live chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251041/php-extract-youtube-live-chat)
2. I have done step 10 and saved the file and is now called [www.youtube.com.har]
3. I opened the .HAR file with Notepad and saved it as a .txt, but it is not readable.

**Problem 4.** Now at step 12 I don't know what to do next.

I used the tool: Rechchat for another thing, but can i also use it to convert a readable .txt file or what other alternatives are there?
https://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Download-Managers/RechatTool.shtml
https://github.com/jdpurcell/RechatTool/releases

Would be nice for instructions on how to get a readable text file.

Comment: Have you tried using some [PHP library](https://github.com/deviantintegral/har) for reading har files?

Comment: I have to be completely honest: I am a beginner in the subject. I followed only the instructions.  Sorry, to be honest, i don't see through that

Comment: I would recommend that you do some research into the subject. A good starting point would be to google something like "reading har files with php" and read through any article/guide/tutorial you find about the subject and test any library you find.